# How to solve "localhost refused the connection" error?

Tags: localhost

I set up a web page on my localhost. I created it using SimpleHTTPServer:

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

It works on Chrome on my PC, but when I try it on Chrome Mobile on a smartphone I keep getting this error: localhost refused the connection,
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED . How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the localhost of your computer, not your phone. . .

If the phone is on the same wifi as the computer - try to connect to the computers (running the server) local IP address.